# Perferct forwarding in initializer_list

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
  template<typename E>
    void insert(E&& e)
    {
        if(nullptr == p){
            p=std::make_unique<Node<T>>();
                p->Root=std::forward<E>(e);}
        else if(e < p->Root)
              p->Left.insert(std::forward<E>(e));
        else
             p->Right.insert(std::forward<E>(e));

    }
    Tree() = default;
    Tree(std::initializer_list<T> lst)
    {
         for(auto e:lst)
             insert(e);
    }
```

The `insert` method is member of class Tree but I don't put the whole class for economy of space. I can provided it if needed. Now to the question: if I change the `auto e:lst` to `auto&& e:lst`
it won't compile because the iterator of std::initializer_list is const. Does this mean that perfect forwarding cannot work in this scenario? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, the elements of `initializer_list` are const, so no forwarding is possible. But you should at least change `auto` to `const auto &` to avoid the copies.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/better_braces, but it fixes thing on the caller side, instead of changing how containers are written.

Comment: The underlying array of `std::initializer_list` holds const objects.  const objects can only be copied.  You can get rid of the copy in the for loop by using `for (const auto& e : lst)`

Comment: Unfortunately, perfect forwarding and initializer lists are allergic to each other.

Comment: Would a constructor like this make any sense (using fold exprssion) ?    `template<typename... args_t>  Tree(args_t&&... args)  { insert(std::forward<args_t>(args)),...);   }`  as far as I can see that will not make any extra copies either, but if  I missed something I will learn something too :) (And I know there should be compile time validation that all args_t are the same as E)

Comment: @PepijnKramer When you do that you need to constrain the template otherwise it becomes a better match in certain cases like when copying a non-const lvalue.  It's not a difficult thing to add but you need to know about it before you can fix it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I suspected something in that direction (hence the compile time validation remark).